# ActiveMQ generates tons of logs on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, activemq-classic

I have web application with ActiveMQ and deploy it to tomcat. The problem is that activemq generates so much debug logs that physical memory on my server clogs quickly. ActiveMQ puts tons of trash to my `catalina.out` and it seems like debug logging, so i [posted some example here](http://pastebin.com/tWn16acT).

I use ActiveMQ 5.8.0, and slf4j/log4j for logging.
The question is: how to configure tomcat/log4j/my webapp to remove those useless ActiveMQ logs?

I tried [this link](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-change-the-logging.html), but it doesnt help.

Comment: Did you manage to work out the solution by any chance? I'm also stuck/annoyed by this issue (Tomcat: 8.5.11, ActiveMQ: 5.14.1, Java: 8 121)



ActiveMQ is just DEBUG logging into catalina.out, really filling up the logs, and nothing I do seems to curb it

Comment: @Gwynnie unfortunately, no.

Comment: So this question is still unanswered?  After so many years I am experiencing this isssue in catalina.out